# Java HashMap<String, Set<Int>> losing set elements after they're added

Tags: java

The purpose of the following code is to take in a title from one book at a time, split it into keywords (anything separated by a space) and map the resulting keywords into a HashMap containing the keyword as the index and a set of integers (representing the position of the book in an ArrayList arrayOfReferences).

```
Set<Integer> toAdd = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (String keyword : addTitle.split(" ")) {
    toAdd.clear();
    if (!searchMap.containsKey(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
        if (!toAdd.contains(arrayOfReferences.indexOf(newBook))) {
            toAdd.add(arrayOfReferences.indexOf(newBook));
            searchMap.put(keyword.toLowerCase(), toAdd);
            System.out.println("New flag: " + keyword + " " + searchMap.get(keyword.toLowerCase()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (Integer addNum : searchMap.get(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
            toAdd.add(addNum);
        }

        System.out.println("Before: " + keyword + " " + toAdd);
        if (!toAdd.contains(arrayOfReferences.indexOf(newBook))) {
            toAdd.add(arrayOfReferences.indexOf(newBook));
            searchMap.put(keyword.toLowerCase(), toAdd);
        }
        System.out.println("After: " + keyword + " " + searchMap.get(keyword.toLowerCase()));
    }
}
```

Currently the code adds the respective indicies to the hashmap, adds the additional positions to the list and then loses the previous values in the list. I'm still very new to Java so the problem could be staring me right in the face, however I need a fresh pair of eyes on it.

Any help is greatly appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining you `Set` in line1:

```
Set<Integer> toAdd = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

And in each loop you are clearing that set (line2 and 3):

```
for (String keyword : addTitle.split(" ")) {
    toAdd.clear();
```

This will modify your already added Set.

I would suggest to create a new Set for each iteration. It's a small change of your code:

```
for (String keyword : addTitle.split(" ")) { // now the first line of code
    Set<Integer> toAdd = new HashSet<Integer>(); // moved inside the loop
    // toAdd.clear(); - not necessary anymore
```

Comment: Thank you so much slartidan! Your solution fixed my problem (curse my inexperience with java.)

Answer (score 1):

`toAdd` is a "reference" to some collection (`Set`) in java `heap`. Every and each loop you have same reference to same collection - and modify data behind it (replace it). Instead, I believe, you expect to create new references to new java objects in `java heap`.
To achive it, instead of

```
- toAdd.clear();
```

You should

```
+ toAdd = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. V! You helped me understand what was actually going wrong with the code and what was needed to fix it.